# Spring injects byte array with one symbol as Byte object

Tags: java, spring, arrays

I have constant with type **byte[]** which contains only one symbol **{ 0 }**. I tried to inject this constant to another bean **SomeBean** which contains method **setSomeField(T field)** through **property** tag.

Type of injected value is parametrized.

I tried to inject this constant through **util:constant** and got **Byte** type instead of **byte[]**. Then I tried to use factory bean with method **byte[] getSomeField()** and got **Byte** type again.

Could somebody explain why this happen? And how can I avoid this behavior?

I created [repository](https://bitbucket.org/user3165215/springbytearray/src/243dceeb1413f77b7eaf6cde1a5f579dc82afc76?at=master) with demonstration of this issue

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it.

Comment: I written example, see link in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Spring beans bug, fixed in version >= 3.2.5